# Query firebase can't get documents in for loop

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to go through a collection called "requests" and get all the strings from fields called "to" from each document and to compare each of them with the username of logged in user. For some reason my app doesn't enter in the for loop, look at the code :

**Fragment.java** :

```
public class PendingFragment extends Fragment implements PendingInterface {
    RecyclerView recyclerViewpending;
    AdapterPending adapterPending;
    ArrayList<Request> requestslist;
    String loggedinusername, currentid, fromuser;
    DocumentReference reference;
    DocumentReference referenceusers;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    FirebaseUser loggedinuser;
    Query mQuery;
    View v;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending, null);
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Log.i("Query" , "logged in user : " + loggedinusername);
        mQuery = firestore.collection("requests")
                .whereEqualTo("to", loggedinusername);
        Log.i(TAG,"query is " + mQuery);
        
          
        recyclerViewpending = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerpending);

        recyclerViewpending.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewpending.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        requestslist = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterPending = new AdapterPending(requestslist,v.getContext());
        adapterPending.setListener(this);
        recyclerViewpending.setAdapter(adapterPending);
        loggedinuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        currentid = loggedinuser.getUid();

        adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();

        referenceusers = firestore.collection("Users").document(currentid);
        referenceusers.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.getResult().exists()){
                    loggedinusername = task.getResult().getString("username");
                    Log.d(TAG,"logged in user : " + loggedinusername);
                }
            }
        });

        mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   Log.d(TAG,"I am in  task.issuccesful " );
                   for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()) {

/* I DON'T RECEIVE THIS MESSAGES BELOW IN MY LOGAT, ONLY THOSE FROM ABOVE */

                       Log.d(TAG,"I am in for ");

                       String tousername = ds.getString("to");
                       fromuser = ds.getString("from");
                       Log.d(TAG,"To : " + tousername);
                       Log.d(TAG,"From :  " + fromuser);
                       if (tousername.equals(loggedinusername)) {
                           Log.d(TAG,"I am in if with equals " + tousername);
                       Request obj = ds.toObject(Request.class);
                       requestslist.add(obj);
                       }
                   adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();

                   }
               }
               else {
                   Log.d(TAG,"Error" + task.getException().getMessage());
               }
           }
       });
```

Image from logcat :
[image]

Please help ! Thanks!

Image updated after adding Log.i :
[image]

Comment: It seems like the `mQuery = firestore.collection("requests").whereEqualTo("to", loggedinusername)` has no results when you execute it. You'll want to check the value of `loggedinusername` in a debugger, and compare it to the database.  --- If after doing that you still think there should be a result, edit the code to log `loggedinusername`, show us the updated code and its output, and a screenshot of a document you'd expect to get back for that query.

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by " edit the code to log loggedinusername" ?

Comment: `Log.i("Query", loggedinusername)` just before the query.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added what you proposed, I see that it returns me null value, so here it's the problem.